# the boundedness on an open interval

Tags: analysis

I am reading the proof of boundedness on E.Hairer's book "Analysis by its history".I will quote his proof first and then give my question

> We first prove that $f(x)$ is bounded on $[a,b]$. We suppose the contrary:
> $$\forall n \geq 1 \quad \exists x_n \in [a,b] \quad s.t. |f(x_n)|>n \quad(3.10)$$
> The sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3$ admist a convergent subsequence by the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem. In order to avoid writing this subsequence with new symbols, we denote it agin by $x_1,x_2,x_3, ...$ and we simply say:" after extracting a subsequence , we suppose that "$ \lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n) = f(\xi)$".Since f is continuous at $\xi$, it follows from $theorem 3.3$ that $lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)=f(\xi)$.This conradicts $(3.10)$ and thus proves the boundedness of $f(x)$.

My question is , we know that this boundedness will not hold for some function in the interval like $[a,b)$, but I am curious which part of the the above proof doesn't hold for such an open interval. Because I can only saw the above proof uses the boundedness of the interval but not the closedness property.

Comment: The part that uses Bolzano-Weierstrass' theorem gives the existence of a limit in the reals, but it is then the closedness of the interval what gives that that limit $\xi$ is inside the interval. If $\xi$ is not in the interval, we were not given information about $f$ there. Perhaps $\xi$ is not in the domain of $f$, or $f$ is not continuous at $\xi$.

Comment: Run the proof with $f:(0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=1/x$ and see where it breaks down.

Comment: The book "Analysis by Its History" was written by E. Hairer and G. Wanner, not by me as is incorrectly stated in the question above.